# Pandas DataFrame Join/Merge based on Like Fields vs. Actual Match

Tags: python, pandas

Have two datasets which I am pulling into Pandas DataFrames out of Teradata.

```
tables=pd.DataFrame(session.execute("select databasename as source_db, tablename as source_obj, databasename||'.'||tablename as full_tablename, tablekind as source_obj_kind from dbc.tables").fetchall()).set_index('databasename')
tvm=pd.DataFrame(session.execute("select tvmname target_obj, tablekind target_obj_kind, createtext from dbc.tvm").fetchall()).set_index('createtext')
```

I am trying to run a join between these two items equivalent to the following Syntax (teradata sql):

```
tvm.createtext like '%"' !! trim (tables.source_db) !! '"."'!! trim (tables.source_obj)!! '"%' (not cs)
```

In layman's terms, where the full_databasename (source_db||'.'||source_obj) from tables is located inside the createtext column in tvm, create a new dataframe.

I'm trying to avoid having to write two for statements which will review each and every row in tables and compare it manually to each and every row in tvm.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at [Pandas Help](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)?  its one line but you need to know join column names.  You can either merge or concat.

Comment: I'm not familiar with teradata sql but if you write an ansi sql I may be able to convert to pandas.

Comment: Note before using this you need to rename the keys to make them identical, you can have multiple on=['a','b']`merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None,
      left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
      suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False)`

Comment: Thanks all. Please note, this is not a true join, but a loose join.  To find a match, the value of source_db||'.'||source_obj must be inside the createtext field.  This means it is not a concat, merge, join.  If i do a full outer join (merge how='outer')  i then have to iterate thru each row to see if full_tablename in createtext.